# How can I make python tts.sapi speak asynchronously?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, voice, sapi

Here is the text to speech code I use in my voicebot program :

```
import tts.sapi

voice = tts.sapi.Sapi()

def say(text):
    voice.say(text)
```

It works great but the thing is I want to be able to interrupt the function if needed.
I mean being able to execute other commands while it speaks (such as saying "stop speaking").

As the say() function is just one command, I can't manage to make it work. However I could do that when I did my voicebot in C# with a method called speakAsync(). Is there such a method in the tts.sapi library? Or using Sapi win32com? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using the tts.sapi wrapper, you'll need to set up an event loop and event interests (so that SAPI will call you back).  Instead, you might want to look at the [pyttsx](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx/1.0/) package.  It appears to support async speaking.